# Excel - Find the biggest gap in a set of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of numbers
0,1,99,5,5,98,9
They are unsorted and will remain that way.
I cannot use macros.
I want the answer 89 from a formula or an array formula.
89 is the biggest gap (between 9 and 98) in this series when sorted.
I want a formula, no vba, and no sorting my column or row.

I need a formula that sorts the list and subtracts one cell relative to the sorted list and gives the largest difference of the list of differences it creates.

so the list becomes 0,1,5,5,9,98,99
subtracts the current from the previous (na,1,4,0,4,89,1)
and gives me the max 89.

My list is a column of 7 rows.

Comment: Can we create a secondary column?

Comment: You've outlined your requirements quite well. The only thing missing is at least some sort of effort to try to solve this yourself. Can you [edit] to include that?

Comment: Plus this is a basic formula question more suited to SuperUser. I have voted for it to be migrated accordingly.

Comment: I don't agree that it's off-topic.

Comment: Nor do I. `MAX` and `LARGE` as per Hugh's answer below are library functions. It's definitely "programming related" to show people how to call library functions or that they exist in the first place.

Comment: I agree the question could be better but those restrictions are pretty common as Excel constraints go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula must be **array-entered**.  In the formula RNG refers to the range where you have entered your numbers, e.g. A1:A7

```
=MAX(LARGE(RNG,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&-1+COUNT(RNG))))-
LARGE(RNG,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&COUNT(RNG)))))
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula.

You can see how the formula works by using the Evaluate Formula option on the Formula Auditing tab of the Formulas ribbon.

In brief, the formula works by creating two arrays, sorted in order of size.  The "K" value of the LARGE function is an array created by the ROW(INDIRECT sequence.  The first returns

```
{1;2;3;4;5;6}
```

and the second returns

```
{2;3;4;5;6;7}
```

The two arrays of values returned would then be:

```
{99;98;9;5;5;1}
{98;9;5;5;1;0}
```

Subtracting one from the other results an array of the differences, and we find the MAX.

Answer (score 1):

`MAX(A:A) - LARGE(A:A,2)` gives the difference between the largest and second-largest value if your numbers are in column A. Don't put this formula in column A.

Comment: This will work for this case. I gave arbitrary numbers. I will fix my question. It will not work in what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Place the values in **A1** thru **A7** in any order!

In **B1** enter:

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$7,0)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)-1
```

and copy down thru **B7**

In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(ROW(),B$1:B$7,0))
```

and copy down thru **C7**

In **D2** enter:

```
=C1-C2
```

and copy down thru **C7**

Finally in **E1** enter:

```
=MAX(C:C)
```

Column **B** represents the *order* of the values in column **A** if they were sorted.  Column **C** contains the values of column **A** in *sorted* order.  Column **D** are the differences and **E1** gives the desired answer.  Here is an example:

[image: demo]

Comment: My heart lies with the "one cell" version, but my head recognizes that this is the better solution unless there is some problem with using intermediate results columns.

Comment: The **array** formula is the "better" solution........the "helper column" approach is easier to understand and to maintain.